# How to send and receive data from serial using analog pins?

Tags: softwareserial, hc-06, rx-pin

I have L293D shield connected to my arduino UNO and it fills nearly all the digital pins including TX(1) and RX(0) pins.
I know this function, but as far as I know, it works for digital pins.

```c
SoftwareSerial NAME(Rx,Tx);
```

How can I set 2 analog pins as Tx and Rx? I will use them for HC-06.

Comment: The analog pins also have all the functionality of general purpose input/output (GPIO) pins (the same as digital pins 0 - 13). You can just declare it as `SoftwareSerial mySerial(A0, A1)`.

Comment: BTW, read the caveats on [Arduino Reference](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/AnalogInputPins) when using the analog pins as GPIO.

Comment: Is the shield really using all these pins, or is it just covering them up?